# Find location of a 3G router with no GPS

Tags: android

I have a project for a company that makes data loggers which send data through an access point. Our team's task is to create an Android app that locates the data logger when it is moving. It does not have GPS, so our only option is to use the location of the portable access point that goes with the data logger. The portable access point uses a SIM card.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to find the location of the 3G router?

Comment: You can map you access point with real map and triangulate you position with rssi level. I am recommend you switching to BLE beacons instead of using WiFi.

Comment: You need to add provider settings, i'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
aLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
```